# Windows Authentication Session State - ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, session-timeout

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that is using windows authentication, configured in IIS 7.5. It prompts the user for their Windows Credentials when they first load the
page.

Now, I want to have the "session" timeout in XX minutes, so that the page
will again prompt them for their credentials if this timeout has elapsed.

I have tried setting the "Session.timeout = XX" in the page_load method of
the page I want to secure.

I notice that the "Session_End" method in Global.Asax does fire, but the
Authentication Ticket appears to "stay valid" even after the Session has
ended.

Is there a way to force the page to prompt again for Windows Credentials at
specified timeouts either by changing configurations in Web.Config or thru IIS?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have control over the allowed session duration when using Windows Authentication, as this is part of the authentication protocol (Kerberos). There are [ways and workarounds](http://forums.asp.net/t/1489931.aspx), but none of them straightforward.

It seems that forcing a client-side `document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");` might come closest to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to achieve this. I've read on people trying to manually control when 401s are sent but from what I remember, I haven't found any reliable solution.